# Error Installing VIsualStudio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to install Microsoft Visual studio but i am constantly getting an Error 1317[image]

I Tried using Error 1317 Repair Tool but it was not free.Is there any anohter way to fix this??
Thanx for the help.

Comment: Are you running the setup with administrative privileges?

Comment: what operating system are you installing vs2010 on? if vista or windows 7 or windows 8, you need to run the set up as an administrator

Comment: Please check this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/872903

Comment: @CodyGray:yah i tried installation with admin privileges.

Comment: @AkshayJoy:I have already tried that solution all administrative privileges are allowd bt still shows the same problem.I am using windoiws 7.

Comment: @Sudiya - If you have privileges,then I dont think so there will not be any issue, please read this http://answers.bloglines.com/home-garden/building-renovations/garages/Error_1317

Comment: yah i found the error with corrupted registry i finally formated pc.Its installed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was error due to some registry files were corrupted.I simply formatted my computer then installed Visual Studio.